# Create a rails route with only parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to create a rails route which has only parametrs. Eg:

```
match '/:taxonomy/:taxon/(:tag)' => 'shop#index', :as => 'shop'
```

Currently I am creating a separate rails route for each possible value of `taxonomy`. E.g.

```
match '/jewellery/:taxon/(:tag)' => 'shop#index', :as => 'shop'
match '/bags-and-wallets/:taxon/(:tag)' => 'shop#index', :as => 'shop'
match '/mens-jewellery/:taxon/(:tag)' => 'shop#index', :as => 'shop'
match '/mens-accessories/:taxon/(:tag)' => 'shop#index', :as => 'shop'
```

If I use `/:taxonomy/:taxon/(:tag)`, some other pages also start getting routed to the `shop_controller`.

Is this possible? Maybe by setting allowed values for the `taxonomy` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Just place your only-parameters-matcher after all others.
i.e. make sure that your route with parameters is the last route in your routes file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I could not understand. PLease can you elaborate a little.